# Deciding between NgComponent and NgDirective

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Is there some rule of thumb to be followed while deciding to implement custom element as `NgComponent` or `NgDirective`?

What are the issues to keep in mind while deciding to choose either of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to add functionality/behavior to existing tags/elements you use a directive (like ng-class or ng-hide).
You can apply a directive to different tags.
To create a new element/tag you create a component (like accordion, carousel, modal, ...).
A component is a new custom element that can have a template that defines its shadow DOM content.

You can use a directive to dynamically add/remove html content too, but with a component you can create new elements that have a clear boundary between inside and outside.
A component has it's own scope that is not part of the application scope hierarchy.
You can't easily reach inside a components content.

Html generated from a directive is like any other html tags. You have transclusion with components (I think someone is working on components without shadow DOM and transclusion like in Angular.js but I don't know how far this is and how this will look like.)

You can use directives inside a component, and a component inside a component.

Comment: Coming from JS world, AngularJS did let me create new elements using directives too, so I don't completely understand why new element implies NgComponent, Isn't there considerations related to Shadow DOM itself? like what if I need to include a component within another component, a directive inside a component etc.? Are these not considerations while deciding?

Comment: I have extended my answer. Please add a comment if there are still open questions.

Comment: Thanks @Gunter, I think this is a good set of starting points to decide!